# generating complex maps in xna

Tags: xna, 2d, textures, maps

I just wonder how does these maps like in this video are made. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TM6kcOau5oQ 
 I was looking for some tutorials on the web but no success. All I found was some 2D Vectors (Matrixes) with 0,1,2 values on it but I think these maps are generated and stored in a different ways. Can somebody help me or give me some advice about these maps. 
 I saw some presentations about indie games and I was just amazed by these games. I want to make my own game. I am a beginner and already started an XNA book and some tutorials. I would like to learn how these games are made. Thanks!

Comment: You might look at [Gleed2D](http://gleed2d.codeplex.com/), and [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) map editors. I don't know if your question can really be answered in its current form, is there something specific you are having trouble with?

Comment: Nobody but the makers of that game can tell you how those maps were made.  More complex maps are generally made with some kind of tool, either a premade one like those linked by John or more tailored one built by the game team for that game/engine specifically.  A few noteworthy games of recent years were indeed built by editing text files like you mentioned; I don't recommend that path.

Comment: @John McDonald, thanks for advance, I will take a look at those programs. I haven't got any problems, I just wondered how these games were made and I thought this place is the best to ask my question because maybe somebody who already made some games could answer my question. It was just a general question about maps.

Comment: @Sean Middleditch, thanks for the answer. I hope I will met some people who could told me how those maps were made. Like I said I searched the net for some kind of tutorials which could show me ow those maps were generated and imported in the games, but no luck. Thank you again guys! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create maps like the one in the video you could start with 'tile-base maps'. Tiled maps implement the idea that your map is created from similiar sized blocks with different textures. There is a [good tutorial for tile based maps with XNA](http://www.xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=Tutorial%3aTileEngineSeries:1). This tutorial explains some of the basics and shows different concepts which may be usefull. You question is very broad, so feel free to refine it, or get in contact if you got any particular problems with your journey in XNA ;)

LostGarden provides you with [some graphics](http://www.lostgarden.com/2007/05/dancs-miraculously-flexible-game.html) to start with[enter link description here](http://www.lostgarden.com/2006/07/more-free-game-graphics.html), if you just want to get your hands dirty with XNA and tile based maps.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! As soon as possible I will vote the answer up. :)